# line order with plotly

Tags: python, plotly

With these two lines of code:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=profits['timestamp'], y=profits['balance'], line_color='green'), secondary_y=False, row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=events['timestamp'], y=(events['s1_held'] + events['s2_held']), line_color='orange'), secondary_y=True, row=2, col=1)
```

the line on the secondary_y axis is always drawn on top.

the order of the calls doesn't matter

how can I specify the drawing order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traces are drawn per subplot (and the secondary axis counts as a subplot) and `make_subplots` draws the secondary above the primary. If you want to change this you will need to create the subplots manually without using `make_subplots` as detailed at the bottom of https://plot.ly/python/subplots/